# synchronous ajax call via jquery returning string

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, synchronous

I am making a jQuery synchronous call to ajax -- with the return type set to "json" --  however the return data is coming back as a string.  Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there away to convert the string to an object?

```
var ajax_response = $.ajax({url:"ajx_services", async:false, type:"post", data:{method: "getItem", item_no: $(ctx).val()}, dataType:"json"});
var data = ajax_response.responseText;
```

The ajax call is working, as I can see the results in the debugger, it is simply that the returned data is in a string.

Answer (score 1):

responseText will always be a string.  within $.ajax() add a 'success' callback function with a parameter and that will be the JSON data.

```
$.ajax({
    -- other stuff --
  , success: function(data)
    {
        // do something with data
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because $.ajax() will return an actual XMLHttpRequest .. whose `responseText` has no concept of JSON etc.

Try this:

```
var data = (function () {
    var ajaxResponse = '';
    $.ajax({url:"ajx_services", async:false, type:"post", data:{method: "getItem", item_no: $(ctx).val()}, success: function (data) {
        ajaxResponse = data;
    }, dataType:"json"}); 
    return ajaxResponse;
}());
```

Since `ajaxResponse` is defined in the parent closure of the function defined in the `ajax()` call, it can be set to the JSON `data` object that is provided by the `success` function (which is called when the Ajax request successfully completes). Then, `ajaxResponse` is returned by the parent closure, which is then assigned to the outside `data` variable.

Note that this ability to immediately return the modified `ajaxResponse` from the `ajax()` is only possible because the request is synchronous. If it were async, `return ajaxResponse` would very likely return an empty string.

Comment: Thanks!! ... worked like a champ;  I was wrongly suspicious of the success function with the async:false.

Answer (score 0):

That way should work, using the eval function:

```
var ajax_response = $.ajax({url:"ajx_services", async:false, type:"post", data:{method: "getItem", item_no: $(ctx).val()}, dataType:"json"});
ajax_response.onreadystatechange = xHandler;

function xHandler() {
  if (ajax_response.readyState == 4) {
    var data = eval('(' + ajax_response.responseText + ')');
  }
}
```

But as it has been said before, **you should use jQuery success callback**, which exists to make your life easier.